# Change item counts in different sizes in owl carousel 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

I`m using owl-Carousel 2 .
I want to change Items Count in different media Queries .
I`m also using Bootstrap ( if it helps with special attrs from html BS )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html), you can use the `responsive` setting to do so, as per their example:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{ //for width 0px and up
            items:1 //show only one item at a time
        },
        600:{ //for width 600px and up
            items:3 //show 3 items at a time
        },
        1000:{ //for width 1000px and up
            items:5 //show 5 items at a time
        }
    }
});
```